# Can python's mechanize extract the text associated with a control?

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize

I'm writing a crawler, and I keep encountering forms controls for which mechanize can give me no information beyond type. Is there any way that I can get the human-readable text associated with the control? I know this is a bit of a fuzzy area, since there's no perfect way of getting that information, but perhaps something can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for text on the sibling nodes and the parent node's text, because that's where they frequently are.  LXML might be able to help if you actually have to parse the html.